# List of recently awarded badges has no correct spacing

Tags: bug, design, badges

When visiting https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges (at this time) the list of badges awarded recently is display with no spacing between them, which I think is incorrect since it doesn't follow the overall site style:

[image]